# Check if user matched

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I need somthing like : `user=[ "jack" "david" "root"]` then check if `$1="david" do something.

Comment: That is not how you create an array via shell syntax.

Comment: Do you use bash or zsh?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and easy way to implement want you want in bash

```
declare -a USERS=("jack" "david" "root")

for i in "${USERS[@]}"
do
    echo "current array entry: $i"
    if [ "$i"  == "$1" ]; then
        echo "Found a match"
        # do something
    fi
done
```

Hope that helped

Comment: I suggest to replace `${USERS[@]}` with `"${USERS[@]}"`. This then also covers the case that the elements could contain spaces.

Comment: thats right!. changed :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are also gave the zsh tag, here is a zsh solution:

```
user=( jack david root )
if (( ${user[(Ie)$1]} > 0 ))
then
  # $1 is in the user list
fi
```

`${user[(Ie)$1]}` calculates the position of $1 in the `user` array, and results in 0 if the user is not present.